# Client validation in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had one register form , and I used to use it with my last asp.net mvc 2 project. Now I copied that register form into my asp.net mvc 3.

These are what I have copied from my last project :

1. All jquery validation + Microsoft mvc ajax files
2. Include all the file in source code
3. Using  `Html.ValidationMessage` in my view.
4. Using  `[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]` in my model

But it still have no the validation script in my view.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft mvc ajax files have been deprecated.

Use the jquery validation scripts supplies with MVC3 instead.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to change all the validation scripts that I had used in mvc2 to the new one in mvc 3, Matt Tew?

Comment: Only if you added custom code for validation, otherwise MVC generates the code for you.